# Почему не работает gulp-sass вместе с gulp-autoprefixer?

Tags: gulp

Содержимое gulpfile.js

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var config = {
    path: {
        scss: './src/scss/**/*.scss',
        html: './public/index.html'
    },
    output: {
        cssName: 'bundle.min.css',
        path: './public'
    }
};

gulp.task('scss', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.path.scss)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat(config.output.cssName))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'IE 8'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.output.path));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scss']);
```

А вот ошибка из консоли

```
gulp                                                                                                                            1 ↵ ──(Чт,ноя02)─┘
[12:45:25] Using gulpfile /var/www/sass.loc/gulpfile.js
[12:45:25] Starting 'scss'...

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: this is not a typed array.
    at Function.from (native)
    at /var/www/sass.loc/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/index.js:25:27
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
```

Если отключаю autoprefixer, то все работает. 
Заранее благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: вы нашли решение данной проблемы?

Comment: У меня тоже самое ошибка. Если нашли решение то сообщите?